# can't request_token from Twitter API

Tags: rest, twitter, restful-authentication

I'm using [REST Console](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher)  chrome app, trying to get token from twitter API using [this method](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/oauth/request_token).

I set the request as POST, set the authorization headers in REST console as follow

```
OAuth oauth_consumer_key="juoUvNrm02wt2RvuLeGKA", oauth_nonce="c79bd7b51dbe23d50f00f3ea3a92e15b", oauth_signature="uq3axrJ8VVgSMcFgpJ3mimCENmk%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1342971727", oauth_callback="https://www.facebook.com/abdelhameed.tourky", oauth_version="1.0"
```

but it's not working and gave "Failed to validate oauth signature and token" status: 401 Unauthorized, 401 Unauthorized

what is wrong?!

Comment: I tried to send the callback parameter URL encoded and still 401

Comment: Do you `Content-Type` header is set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ? Do your signature method works fine ? Does it works correctly with other programs like REST Console (for example curl, Mozilla Firebug, Opera Dragonfly, ...). If you follow what Twitter says ( https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request ), it should not raise problems.
One more thing, keep your callback URL percent encoded.

Comment: yes, content type is ...
the signature method, currently I use the oAuth tool in Twitter, under my app there.

Comment: actually I found something wrong.
I'm using the signature from Twitter oAuth tool, this tool add the token to the signature, but this request don't need a token, so the signature is wrong, is it!?

Comment: You need the `Authorization` header for this `POST https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token` method. It is written in the official Twitter documentation ( https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter ). In the header, there is not any `oauth_token` parameter. It is logical since you are asking Twitter for that. In the key for the signature process, consider the `oauth_token_secret` as an empty string.